# Adharma must prevail in this very Yuga?

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, yuga, life, manu-smriti

Quoting Shastras from reputable sources:

"Manu Smriti says:

> 1.85. One set of duties (is prescribed) for men in the Krita age, different ones in the Treta and in the Dvapara, and (again) another (set) in the Kali, in a proportion as (those) ages decrease in length.

> 1.86. In the Krita age the chief (virtue) is declared to be (the performance of) austerities, in the Treta (divine) knowledge, in the Dvapara (the performance of) sacrifices, in the Kali liberality alone.

The Dharma for Krita is therefore performance of austerities (Tapas) which isn't possible without Indriya Nigraha and restraint in eating for a long period of time.

But the nature of Kali Yuga is such that beings of this age are dependent on food. They are also attracted towards sensual pleasures to a great extent. So, naturally it is not possible for them to follow the Dharma of Krita Yuga.

> But since the men of the Kali Age are full of greed, lust, gluttony, they will on that account neglect sidhana and will fall into sin, and having drunk much wine for the sake of the pleasure of the senses, will become mad with intoxication, and bereft of all notion of right and wrong (61). Some will violate the wives of others, others will become rogues, and some, in the indiscriminating rage of lust, will go (whoever she be) with any woman (62). Over eating and drinking will disease many and deprive them of strength and sense.
> (Mahanirvana Tantra's Chapter 1 verses)"

QUESTION: Is this the reason why all around me is Adharmic?
If I stop to be Dharmic will I stop to suffer then?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When Kali Yuga is in full flow, Adharma will indeed prevail. Out of the 4 feet of the Dharma-Bull only one viz: the Truth foot, is intact in Kali Yuga. But then again people are hardly truthful in this age. So, even the last leg is gone. Therefore, In Kali Yug, Dharma is almost non-existent.

Lord Sadashiva says in this regard:

> In speaking of the customs of the different Ages, I have, O Gentle
> One! and out of love, O Parvati! truly recounted to Thee the signs of
> the dominance of the Kali Age (72). **When the Kali Age is made
> manifest, piety is enfeebled and Truth alone remains; therefore should
> one be truthful** (73). O Thou Virtuous One! know this for certain,
> that whatsoever man does with Truth that bears fruit (74). There is no
> Dharmma higher than Truth, there is no sin greater than falsehood;
> therefore should man seek protection under Truth with all his soul
> (75). Worship without Truth is useless, and so too without Truth is
> the Japa of Mantras and the performance of Tapas. It is in such cases
> just as if one sowed seed in salt earth (76).
>
> **Mahanirvana Tantram, Chapter 4.**

Thus if you want to remain Dharmic amidst Adharma, then that's a tough ask. Because you will receive severe resistance as you are trying to swim against the tide.

But have a look at the following verses (from the same chapter) which give us hope:

> The Kali Age cannot harm those who are purified by truth, who have
> conquered their passions and senses, who are open in their ways,
> without deceit, are compassionate and follow the Kaula doctrine (57).
> The Kali Age cannot harm those who are devoted to the services of
> their Guru, to the lotus of their mothers' feet, and to their own
> wives (58). The Kali Age cannot harm those who are vowed to and
> grounded in truth, adherents of the true Dharmma, and faithful to the
> performance of Kaulika rites and duties (59). The Kali Age cannot harm
> those who give to the truthful KaulikaYogi the elements of worship,
> which have been previously purified by Kaulika rites (60)

Comment: Rudra Rudra Maha Rudra! Aghoraya Apayanthaye ! Dhanyabada @Rickross

Comment: Dhanyabaad @hindustudent-TheWhiteHindu....

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03189.htm

Acts of Kali Yuga

> O tiger among kings, **when the end of the Yuga will come**, the wife will never be content with her husband, nor the husband with his wife. And the possessions of men will never be much, and people will falsely bear the marks of religion, and jealousy and malice will fill the world. And no one will, at that time, be a giver (of wealth or anything else) in respect to any one else. **And the inhabited regions of the earth will be afflicted with dearth and famine, and the highways will be filled with lustful men and women of evil repute**.

Legs of Dharma

> O bull of the Bharata race, listen to me as I narrate the future history of the world during the sinful age. O bull of the Bharata race, in the Krita age, everything was free from deceit and guile and avarice and covetousness; and morality like a bull was among men, with all the four legs complete. In the Treta age sin took away one of these legs and morality had three legs. In the Dwapara, sin and morality are mixed half and half; and accordingly morality is said to have two legs only. In the dark age (of Kali), O thou best of the Bharata race, morality mixed with three parts of sin liveth by the side of men. Accordingly morality then is said to wait on men, with only a fourth part of itself remaining.

Satya Yuga had 4 legs.

> **O bull of the Bharata race, in the Krita age, everything was free from deceit and guile and avarice and covetousness**; and morality like a bull was among men, with all **the four legs complete**.

Treta Yuga had 3 legs

> In the Treta age sin took away one of these legs and morality had three legs.

Dwapara Yuga

> In the Dwapara, sin and morality are mixed half and half; and accordingly morality is said to have two legs only.

Kali Yuga has only one leg of dharma

> **In the dark age (of Kali), O thou best of the Bharata race, morality mixed with three parts of sin liveth by the side of men.** Accordingly morality then is said to wait on men, **with only a fourth part of itself remaining.**

Kali Yuga has the least amount of the legs of dharma, that is why this the yuga filled with most adharma.